# IIS 8.5 Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-8.1

The program will upload a picture and saved it in a virtual directory folder. I encounter this error and I follow the suggestions as suggested in stackOverview and still cannot resolve the issues.

The message simply says the IIS 8.5 doesn't have permission to access to the folder and save a picture in that particular folder. So,I give full permission to the following roles

1. Everyone - Full Control
2. IUSR - Full Control
3. Network Service - Full Control
4. Users - Full Control
5. Guest - Full Control![enter image description here][1]
6. IIS_IUSR - FUll Control
7. ANONYMOUS LOGIN - Full Control
8. DefaultAppPool - Fullcontrol

It is confirmed that Anonymous Authentication is enabled and the specific user is IUSR.
![enter image description here][2]

The detail error message is as below. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.]
>      System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +13946990
>      System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost) +350
>      TakePicture.files_FileUploaded(Object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TownCouncilMobile\ReportDefect2\TakePicture.aspx.vb:45
>      Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +199
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +333
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3572

It has been 3 days as I am still stuck in this problem.

Comment: Is `DefaultAppPool` the application pool identity of the app?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help someone with the same problem. Change Identity for your app pool to LocalSystem.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer leads to elevating privileges for the application running in IIS. This could have negative security implications and should be avoided.